# Alternative for children() and Slice() Methods in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using children() and slice() methods in my script. I need another alternative for that without using this methods.

This is what I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/XVdfm/3/

Comment: What's wrong with your current method?

Comment: perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954342/getting-a-range-of-elements-in-one-jquery-selector

Comment: @xdazz: there was occuring a problem when I am embedding this script in my project

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding all the children, then showing some of them, just hide the ones you don't want:

```
$('#thumbs').children().filter(function(index) {
    return (index < newstart || index >= newlimit);
}).hide();
```

---

If you also want your results to include descendants of `div.video`, you can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('#thumbs').find(".UiUx3DSSVFlow").filter( /*...*/ ).hide();
```

Comment: Can you please send the Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$("ul.topnav > li").css("border", "3px double red");
```

this will let you select the `li`'s inside the `ul` with class `topnav`