# Speed up modifying range of table cells (row/column selection) based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am writing a jQuery Availability Calendar that basically displays a massive table. How massive? There are thirty-four rows and a column for every day in the past two years, current year, and future two years. I'll do the math for you: over 62,000 table cells.

Yes, this loads a little slowly, but once it's loaded, the calendar fits precisely within our needs. There's just one problem:

Users need to be able to select a block of cells. I have everything set up within the UI to allow the user to draw a box around a group of cells, selecting all cells within the box. It's the process of actually marking them "selected" that is painfully slow. Here's the looping code I use:

```
while(r<=thisRow) {
            for(var c=startColumn;c<=thisColumn;c++) {
                if($(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").attr('selectable')=='YES') {
                    if (toggleDirection==0) { $(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").removeClass('selected'); $(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").html(''); }
                    if (toggleDirection==1) { $(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").addClass('selected'); $(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").html($(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]").attr('label')); }
                }

            }
            r++;
}
```

As you can see, I'm having to select by the value of column and row custom attributes. I can not embed these into the cell's ID because there is another process that has equal need for speed already using the ID value. If the ID value contained row and column information, this other function would break, and it would then require the use of custom attributes, therefore running into the same problem I'm having here.

Is there a way to speed up this selection process? The loop itself doesn't take long (if I comment out the jQuery stuff, it runs super fast). So I need a way of forcing jQuery to make a faster job of performing these tasks based on the value of custom attributes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put them in the "class", like `class="row:22 column:3"`? Then you could construct classnames, which might be faster (depending on the browser).

Comment: What I do in a similar case (about the same number of cells than you) is I give as ID of my cells "22_33"

Comment: Do you seriously load 62k+ table cells in one browser page?

Comment: @mori57 You can build very big tables dynamically. When done properly, you'd be amazed at what you can put in your browser...

Comment: @dystroy : Just because you can doesn't mean you should, IMO. I can't conceive of any situation where a human's eye could properly distinguish, in any usable fashion, 62,000+ table cells, unless you're really into pointillism! :) I'd be really interested in what kind of memory use that table causes, fully loaded, as I doubt that they are just simple cells with no contents.

Comment: @mori57 [Look at this](http://canop.org/chrall/galerie.php). The map is a table, centered and scrolled with the mouse. It can get very big sometimes and it keeps being very fast.

Comment: @Pointy That's a good point, but I'm building this for Chrome, and this makes the page load insanely slower. (Like, 15 seconds per row.) I assume this is due to Chrome creating classes for these "pseudo-classes".

Comment: @inveni0 hmm really?  I don't think I've ever noticed Chrome having problems with something as trivial as a few classnames on table cells (or whatever they are).

Comment: @mori57 Actually, most cells are empty. The entire calendar loads at once in order to make navigating it easy (without having to reload the page). The entire calendar isn't visible at once, but it is "available". When the user selects a date, the data for that date range is then pulled into the existing table, as opposed to having to refresh the page to load the data. This is a massive time saver and creates a more enjoyable user experience.

Comment: @Pointy The problem is that there are 62000 classnames...not a few. This is because the browser seems to be creating classnames for c0-c1500 and r0-r34. When it comes to an acceptable number of classnames, having to create 1500+ on the fly might be what's causing the slowdown. All I know for sure is that removing these pseudo-classes reverts loading speeds back to normal.

Comment: @inveni0 I guess it's just surprising that the browser has to "create" anything at all; they're just strings.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah. I would think it would just ignore them. But it's obviously doing something, because removing them solves the issue. Strange, for sure.

Comment: @inveni0: It just seems that this would be a perfect case for something along the lines of KnockoutJS. You could still have your data preloaded (if you really thought you needed it all on demand like that), but wire it up to a templated file, rather than having to manually manage the wiring of the data and presentation together so tightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; Do *not* try to select each element row by column, especially with selectors that must painstakingly search many elements and the corresponding attributes.

This is how I would initial try to solve it:

First, select the *first* row using jQuery - i.e. `row = $("#calendar .calendar_slot:first")[0]` or whatever is appropriate. Then, iterate through the DOM nodes using [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling). Stop iterating when the last row index selected is reached. It is imperative that this loop operation is *relatively fast* under the assumption that rows dominate columns which is why I recommend simple DOM operations and a "range scan". (Alternatively, this might be doable in jQuery selector syntax using the [next sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) and/or [range selectors](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and/or `jQuery.slice`.)

For each row iterated above, use something similar to:

```
$(row).children(".calendar_slot[selectable]").each(function () {
  var colNum = +this.column
  if (colNum > x && colNum < y) {
    var col = $(this)
    // do stuff with col here: only wrapped once!
  }
}
```

Note that the selector is *only executed once* per row; in addition it only needs to look at [child elements](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Unlike iterating the rows above, "slower" jQuery is adequate here and so should be preferred.

Also, consider [jQuery Range Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954342/getting-a-range-of-elements-in-one-jquery-selector); I'd play around with both approaches to see which one(s) meet your goals. It may be the case that range selectors could entirely mitigate my suggestion for selecting rows above and they might make a nice addition to the column selector and eliminate the explicit conditional.

Comment: Perfect! I combined this with @Steve Wellens' solution, and the iteration is now much, much faster. Selecting 9 cells now takes about a second. Thanks! I did it by looping through the rows with a while loop and skipped nextSibling altogether.

Comment: @inveni0 A second still seems sluggish, but glad that it's already a big improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use temp variables to avoid repeating searches, example:

```
var $RC = $(".calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]")
```

Also,  if you can narrow down the search by limiting it with a container element, it would be faster:

```
 $("#container_div  .calendar_slot[row="+r+"][column="+c+"]")
```

Comment: Your solution has cut the time to iterate in half, but it's still not as fast as I'd like. For instance, selecting 9 squares takes about 3 seconds instead of 7.